# How to put signal and wifi signals on left leaving battery and notifs on right

Tags: custom-roms, system, system-apps, user-interface, themes

[image]

Here is what I want my status bar to look like. **edited from photo below**

[image]

Here is my status bar now.

Im new to this android stuff. All I know is i need to decompile my SystemUI.apk and framework-res.apk Im still lost what to do next. The centered clock is an adjustable feature that my ROM has.

Please Help.
OS version: Android 5.1

Tried Gravity Box and Lolistat. I didn't find what  I was looking for.

Comment: We can assume that your device is rooted. Right? Also, would an alternative way suffice or would you still want to prefer only the decompiling stuff?

Comment: Yes it is. I already got both of the .apk

Comment: @Firelord sure i would like to know other ways. Im searching for xposed modules. but got no luck with them.

Comment: did you look at this module GravityBox?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I would try that as a Last resort since my ROM is Cyanogen Based.. Thats why I would want to learn what to do after decompiling the APKs.

Comment: ok. Maybe Lolistat?

Comment: Actually I haven't flashed Xposed yet. Maybe I'll try later. Still looking for some theme modifying tutorials.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury tried GravityBox and Lolistat. It got nothing that i was looking for. I think I have to hardcode it in SystemUI and/or framework-res..

Comment: Good luck. What you are planning on doing counts as development, and isn't supported here.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I believe what OP is trying to do comes under the hobbies of a *power user*. It seems border line to me but I wouldn't call it a development question. However, given the nature of the question and the limited variety of power user questions posted here, the chances of receiving a working answer seems low to me.

Comment: @Firelord, Hardcoding something in System-UI isn't considered development? Then what is?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury As I said, kind of things for **power users** but I also said it is borderline because one way or the other the expertise it requires comes from programming. In any case, I find the question valuable here and *that is strictly my opinion*.

Comment: @Firelord, I find it valuable here too. Just noting that it is a bit out of our area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Finally!]

After hours of digging google, finally found an alternative way to hard-coding.

I used an Xposed module > Flat Style Bar Indicators.

Got the Signal bars and battery separated but the notifications are still on the left side. Well, this will do.